# Trying to develop a web portal that reflects users and scores using django framework

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to develop the scoreboard website which will reflect the users and their respective scores, but i am facing a lot of issues to develop ,since i am new to django framework and python, any help would be appreciated.

below the code for the scoreboard which i am getting errors.if someone has come across or developed a scoreboard please help me out with the code.
thank you!

models.py

```
class member1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ',' + self.contact_number + ',' + self.yourpost + " , " + str(self.department).upper()


class Score(models.Model):
    granted_by = models.ForeignKey(member1, default=0)
    granted_to = models.ForeignKey(member1, default=0, related_name="granted_to")

class priority(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(member1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.ForeignKey(member1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.ForeignKey(member1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
            return str(self.link) + ',' + str(self.number)
    def alpha_name(self):
            return str(self.link.name)

    def score(self):
            return str(score)


member1_choice = [
    i.tuple() for i in member1.objects.all()
]

consult_choice = [
    i.tuple() for i  in consultant.objects.all()
]
```

Comment: What are the issues you are facing! be specific.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: I can understand you're a beginner but please, take some time learning the actual language and framework you use. We can't help fix this code, it's got way too many obvious syntax errors. Spend a week (at minimum) learning python first, then spend a week on the django tutorial.

Comment: when i run python manage.py makemigrations i get this error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django.scoreboard_member1' doesn't exist")"

Comment: yes since i am new to programming ,i will spend my time in learning first .thank you!

Answer (score -1):

you made two mistakes from your side, one adds all foreign key related name in the model **priority** and comments the member1_choice and consult_choice code, please run the **python manage.py makemigrations** command after this you will comments out the code because it's created the dependency.

I modified your code please have a look.

```
class member1(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ',' + self.contact_number + ',' + self.yourpost + " , " + str(self.department).upper()


class Score(models.Model):
    granted_by = models.ForeignKey(member1, default=0)
    granted_to = models.ForeignKey(member1, default=0, related_name="granted_to")

class priority(models.Model):
    link = models.ForeignKey(member1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='priority_link')
    score = models.ForeignKey(member1, on_delete=models.CASCADE,      related_name='priority_score')
    name = models.ForeignKey(member1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='priority_name')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.link) + ',' + str(self.number)
    def alpha_name(self):
        return str(self.link.name)

    def score(self):
        return str(score)


member1_choice = [
    i.tuple() for i in member1.objects.all()
]

consult_choice = [
i.tuple() for i  in consultant.objects.all()
]
```

Comment: This is not an answer, the code is still full of trivial python errors.

Comment: when i run python manage.py makemigrations this is the error which i get 
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'django.scoreboard_member1' doesn't exist")